# Vue js select option in select on click of outside button

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

On click of outside button I would like to select the first option of a select button if unselected.

```
<select name="shareFrequency" class="default-input" v-model="frequency>
     <option value="">Select frequency</option>
    <option v-for="frequency in frequencies" :value="frequency"/>{{ frequency.label }}</option>
</select>

<button id="SelectButton" onclick="selectfirst(this)" type="button">Select frequency</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `v-on:blur` for this, call a method on `v-on:blur` which will select the first option from the array.

```
<select name="shareFrequency" class="default-input" v-model="frequency" v-on:blur="selectFirst">
    <option value="">Select frequency</option>
    <option v-for="frequency in frequencies" :value="frequency"/>{{ frequency.label }}</option>
</select>
```

`selectFirst` will be the method which will set `this.frequency` to `frequencies[0]`.

You can see the use of `v-on:blur` in this [page](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Two-Way-Filters-replaced).